# Python won't print expression

Tags: python, printing

So, I'm kind of new to programming and have been trying Python. I'm doing a really simple program that converts usd to euroes.

This is the text of the problem that I'm trying to solve

> You are going to travel to France. You will need to convert dollars to euros (the
>   currency of the European Union). There are two currency exchange booths. Each has
>   a display that shows CR: their conversion rate as euros per dollar and their fee as a
>   percentage. The fee is taken before your money is converted. Which booth will give
>   you the most euros for your dollars, how many euros, and how much is the difference.
>   Example 1:
>   Dollars: 200
>   CR1: 0.78
>   Fee: 1 (amount 152.88 euros)
>   CR2: 0.80
>   Fee: 3 (amount 155.2 euros)
>   Answer: 2 is the best; difference is 2.32 euros; 155.2 euros

And here is my code

```
    from __future__ import division

usd = int(input("How much in USD? "))
cr1 = int(input("What is the convertion rate of the first one? "))
fee1 = int(input("What is the fee of the first one? "))

cr2 = int(input("What is the convertion rate of the second one? "))
fee2 = int(input("What is the fee of the second one? "))

def convertion (usd, cr, fee):
    usdwfee = usd - fee
    convert = usdwfee * cr
    return convert

first = convertion(usd, cr1, fee1)
second = convertion(usd, cr2, fee2)

fs = first - second
sf = second - first

def ifstatements (first,second,fs,sf):
    if first < second:
        print "1 is the best; difference is ",fs," euroes. 2 converts to ",first," euroes."
    elif first > second:
        print "2 is the best; difference is",sf," euroes. 2 converts to", second," euroes."

ifstatements(first, second, fs, sf)
```

The problem is that when I run the program it won't print out. It just takes my input and doesn't output anything.

Comment: Make sure `first != second`. This seems to work fine for me.

Comment: You should debug your code a) using a debugger - set a breakpoint somewhere at the beginning and execute line by line to see what is happening; or b) just add some prints all over the code to see what gets executed and what the values of the variables are.

Comment: Then if it still does not work and you cannot figure out why, you can google your exact problem and ask a specific question here when that fails ;)

Comment: Can I ask you a question? Given that you are just starting learning python, why are you learning using a python version that is **at least** 6 years old?  Please use a recent python version like python3.3/3.4/3.5 instead of learning on a deprecated version like python2.7

Comment: If you are using 2.7 then you probably need `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your logic more.

`cr1 = int(input("What is the convertion rate of the first one? "))`

Your conversion rate is in int. As in Integer which means it can't have a floating point (a decimal "CR1: 0.78" from your example). Your cr1 will become 0 if you cast it into an int. Also change your dollar and fees to accept floats too since I'm assuming you want to deal with cents too

So change:

```
usd = float(input("How much in USD? "))
cr1 = float(input("What is the convertion rate of the first one? "))
fee1 = float(input("What is the fee of the first one? "))

cr2 = float(input("What is the convertion rate of the second one? "))
fee2 = float(input("What is the fee of the second one? "))
```

And it should work.